# Redirect all traffic to https://www.example.com

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, server, lets-encrypt

Hi I'm trying to redirect `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, `www.example.com` to **`https://www.example.com`**

For that i'm using the apache configuration as follow:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    # Turn on mod rewrite
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</Directory>
```

The above setting is working for `www.example.com` but when i enter domain without `www` browser show warning message.

One more thing i've installed ssl certificate (let's encrypt) for both domains `example.com`, `www.example.com`. But i've installed these certificates one by one seperately, at first for `example.com` then `www.example.com`. Please tell me why redirect is not working and why browser show warning message for `example.com`, when i've certificate for both domain.

Comment: Please indicate what warning message is shown by your browser for the non-www URL. Can you confirm via a tool such as SSL Labs that your certificate is valid for www and non-www?

Comment: Now i've deleted both the certificates and reinstalling it again, but initially ssllabs showing certificate is valid for both www and non www. One thing why my redirect is not working non www to www. Where is the problem in my code.

Comment: I was getting the error "Server's certificate doe not match the url".

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

For more detailed information you can also refer https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/

Comment: Thanks i'll try then let you know.

Comment: It works. I also want to redirect ip address to `https://www.example.com` domain name. Is it possible?

Comment: It has one more problem it somebody put wwww instead of www by mistake it redirects to `https://www.wwww.example.com` instead of `https://www.example.com` and browser show warning message.